# Linux access windows share without loading to RAM

Tags: files, windows, performance, shared-library

I have a laptop running an Arch-based Linux system and frequently need to access a windows share at my workplace. This is really annoying since it takes ages to load. Particularly, one folder is really bad where >5000 pdf files are stored (>10 GB). I have to browse this folder frequently since it contains literature for my work. My RAM is limited (4 GB) and the performance of my laptop is really down while it takes an hour or so to more or less fully load this folder...

Is there any way to circumvent this problem ie. increase the performance? I don't need to load every file in this folder, I just want to browse the names and pick one file or so. I am not familiar with how this would work but isn't there a way to just load the file list? Preferably, I would like to do this in a GUI.

I cannot change the folder structure nor the windows share.

#### Furter specifications:

- My system: `Manjaro 18.0.2`.
- Access of the windows share via `Nemo` (when accessed via terminal it went unresponsive as well!)
- Mount point of the share is in my home folder.
- Access of the windows share is via the University VPN and I am using it from work and from home.
- I reduced the `swapiness` of my system to `10`

#### `fstab` info

I load the windows share with the following specifications in my `fstab`:

```
/path/to/windows/share  /home/user/WindowsShare cifs vers=3.0,users,credentials=/home/user/.smbcredentials,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
```

Comment: Note that `ls` etc. usually try to sort files, and doesn't do so very efficiently. What happens if you access (e.g. `cp`) a file using the full file name from the terminal? That shouldn't be slow, unless something else is wrong. For browsing, could you store file listing as a text file on your laptop, or does this share change often?

Comment: Good idea! I will try to get the file list to my computer (it is not often changing). Thanks :)

Comment: But still, it takes ages if I just `cd` into the folder and then try to `cp` with suggestions...

Comment: That's why I said "full file name". "Suggestions" will again try to read the whole directory... So don't `cd`, remember the file name.

Comment: Ok, got it! (don't if this question should be left open now!?)

Comment: How is the Windows share mounted on your laptop? CIFS? gvfs?

Comment: It's a workaround, it doesn't solve the actual problem (finding out *why* directory access is so slow, and fixing it). So maybe someone has a proper answer...

Comment: Sorry, not entirely clear to me: relatively to your laptop, is the Windows share always remote (accessed through a VPN, over the Internet), or sometimes local (e.g. at your workplace) and sometimes remote?

Comment: I always access it through a VPN, even if I'm at my workplace (the university by the way...)